# Trying to get my game running in VC 2010, can't seem to link SOIL library, don't know how to link, game source code included

Tags: c++, linker

I've been using CodeBlocks for a while now as I make a little hobby game in C++. Come across a snag whereby I want to see the current values of all the data in my arrays at any point, CodeBlocks doesn't seem to have that ability. Have been told by workmates (professional game programmers) that I should use Visual Studio.

Have previously used Visual Studio C# in the past, was very handy being able to use a break point while debugging other small games I've made and then going through the big list of watches to look at particular array values or any other value from within my program at that time.

So I've created a new blank project in VC2010 and added all my code files to the project.  I know I have to link libraries and such, have spent the last few hours trying to figure out how to do that.  But even after all that is done, I'm still getting link errors (I think)

First problem is this:

```
fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'gl\glext.h': No such file or directory
```

So I commented it out to see how much further I could get.

Eventually had to add to my main.cpp file

```
#pragma comment (lib, "opengl32.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "glu32.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "libsoil.lib")
```

I ended up copying the **libsoil.a** file to C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\lib and renaming it to **libsoil.lib** (as stated on the authors's website http://www.lonesock.net/soil.html)

So now I get this when I compile

```
1>libsoil.lib(stb_image_aug.o) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___chkstk referenced in function _stbi_zlib_decode_noheader_buffer
1>libsoil.lib(image_helper.o) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _sqrtf referenced in function _RGBE_to_RGBdivA2
1>C:\Repositories\HappyHelperPuppy\CppVer\HappyHelperPuppy\Debug\HappyHelperPuppy.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
```

..And I have no idea what to do next. I've spent ages in Google and trawling through forums and I really just don't know what to do.

So as a last ditch effort I'm zipping up all my code and project files and letting anyone whos interested to have a look and see if they can find a solution.  It's not like this game will have any secret feature I want to keep under wraps, and all the art is from an open game competition from ages ago ("TIGSource Assembly" for those who know what it is) or from DeviantArt (just wanted something to look at while I made it, wouldn't be final game release art)

The code/game can be found here http://users.on.net/~infernoraven/hhp_busted_code.zip (27mb)

The SOIL library should be in the main directory in its own soil.zip

Any help would be good, but I'm just getting really depressed as I seem to spend most of my time either fighting with the IDE/Compilers or some annoying syntax problem.

The CodeBlocks project files should be in there also, so if you..

- un-comment out **glext.h**
- link to SOIL
- link to libopengl32 and libglu32

Hopefully it'll compile for you.  Otherwise there should be an HappyHelperPuppy.exe that's precompiled by CodeBlocks that should hopefully run and give you an idea of what is suppose to happen

---

In the SOIL package there are a number of project files for visual studio.  When I try to load up the VC9 one and convert it to VC10, I get conversion errors.

```
Conversion Report - SOIL.vcproj: 
Converting project file 'C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\Downloads\soil\Simple OpenGL Image Library\projects\VC9\SOIL.vcproj'. 
Failed to upgrade platform 'x64'. Please make sure you have it installed under '%vctargetspath%\platforms\x64' 
VCWebServiceProxyGeneratorTool is no longer supported. The tool has been removed from your project settings. 
Attribute 'Detect64BitPortabilityProblems' of 'VCCLCompilerTool' is not supported in this version and has been removed during conversion. 
Attribute 'Detect64BitPortabilityProblems' of 'VCCLCompilerTool' is not supported in this version and has been removed during conversion. 
Failed to upgrade 'Debug|x64'. Please make sure you have the corresponding platform installed under '%vctargetspath%\platforms\x64' 
The project configuration dimension name/value "(Platform, Win32)" was not found in the project manifest. 
Project upgrade failed.
```

If I use the VC8 project file and try to upgrade that, a libSOIL.lib file is generated by VC2010 throws an error saying "Unable to start program ... \SOIL.lib The specified file is an unrecognized or unsupported binary format"

But the author on his site states that I can simply rename the libSOIL.a file to a libSOIL.lib file and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

The soil.zip file contains some .sln files under the folder projects. Use the proper .sln file to build the library, then link your project against this library. It worked fine on my side.

Comment: Using the VS8 one, it complains that the Soil.lib file (that I think it generates) ..."is an unrecognized or unsupported binary format".  If I use VS9, it gets conversion errors.  Stuff to do with x64.  Would make a mess if I pasted it here

Comment: I did the build here with VS 2010 on an x32 machine. I suggest you fix the conversion errors, because you're close to your goal, or try an x32 machine.

Comment: I'm not sure how to fix the conversion errors :\  I don't know what they mean.  That aside, why would I need to compile the library when I just rename the libsoil.a file as the author states?

Comment: I thought that's what I was using, I'm on WinXP 32 bit, and VS2010 Express I think only allows me to create 32bit programs (from what I was reading on MS)

Comment: Than what do you mean by "stuff to do with x64"?